# Static route via nftables firewall

Tags: firewall, nat, centos8, nftables, static-routes

I have a gateway "X" with 2 NICs

enp0s3 (192.168.0.100) connected to 192.168.0.0/24 (let's assume this is a WAN network)

enp0s8 (172.16.0.1) connected to 172.16.0.0/24 (presumably a LAN network)

I have created a NAT connection using nftables to allow hosts in the LAN (172.16.0.0/24) browse the internet via the gateway "X".

/etc/nftables/nftables_firewall

```
flush ruleset
table inet filter {
  chain input {
    type filter hook input priority 0; policy drop;
    ct state {established, related} accept
    ct state invalid drop
    iifname lo accept
    iifname enp0s8 accept
    ip protocol icmp accept
    reject
  }

  chain forward {
    type filter hook forward priority 0;
    oifname enp0s3 accept
    iifname enp0s3 ct state related, established accept
    iifname enp0s3 drop
  }

  chain output {
    type filter hook output priority 0;
  }

}
```

/etc/nftables/nftables_nat

```
flush ruleset
table ip nat {
  chain prerouting {
    type nat hook prerouting priority 0;
  }

  chain postrouting {
    type nat hook postrouting priority 0;
    oifname enp0s3 masquerade
  }
}
```

Now, I need a host (192.168.0.101) which is a laptop from the WAN (192.168.0.0/24 network) to access hosts in the LAN (172.16.0.0/24 network) via the gateway "X". i.e. I need to configure a static route from this host (192.168.0.101) in the WAN to the LAN (172.16.0.0/24 network).

This is the static route I am trying to add on the laptop that is on the 192.168.0.0/24 network via its wlo1 interface

```
ip route add 172.16.0.0/24 via 192.168.0.100 dev wlo1
```

The rules in the gateway firewall are blocking these packets from entering the 172.16.0.0/24 network.

How do I allow this on my gateway?

I know the packets are being dropped by the firewall rules because

testing with

```
ping 172.16.0.2
```

from 192.168.0.101 while running

```
tcpdump -lnni any src 192.168.0.101
```

from the gateway "X" replies

```
11:41:53.240815 IP 192.168.0.101 > 172.16.0.2: ICMP echo request, id 8, seq 1, length 64
11:41:54.243947 IP 192.168.0.101 > 172.16.0.2: ICMP echo request, id 8, seq 2, length 64
11:41:58.247687 ARP, Request who-has 192.168.0.100 tell 192.168.0.101, length 46
```

Comment: I have added as much verbosity as possible. Apologies for the lack of clarity. I thought this was a common setup.

Comment: Answer made. And to be honest I just misread the question before.

Answer (score 0):

Your *two* rulesets have a flaw:

> ```
> flush ruleset
> ```

If both are executed in sequence, because of `flush ruleset` only the last will remain.

Each `flush ruleset` should should be changed into respectively:

```
table inet filter
delete table inet filter
```

and:

```
table ip nat
delete table ip nat
```

to get each time an idempotent table definition that won't fail at first use nor duplicate itself nor affect the *other* table.

---

Now about the question, it's as simple as inserting a forward rule to allow this at the right place: before the drop rule, so either of:

```
# nft insert rule inet filter forward index 2 ip saddr 192.168.0.101 ip daddr 172.16.0.0/24 accept
```

or else:

```
# nft add rule inet filter forward index 1 ip saddr 192.168.0.101 ip daddr 172.16.0.0/24 accept
```

to test,

or else directly by editing the ruleset at the right place to keep it:

```
...
iifname enp0s3 ct state related, established accept
ip saddr 192.168.0.101 ip daddr 172.16.0.0/24 accept
iifname enp0s3 drop
...
```

The rule can be optionally added a `iifname enp0s3` (=> `iifname enp0s3 ip saddr 192.168.0.101 ip daddr 172.16.0.0/24 accept`) for extra safety.

The return traffic is already handled by the stateful rule (`... ct state related, established ...`).

Comment: I stand corrected about using flush ruleset. 
merged the two files in to one file.

Applied your changes with 
````
iifname enp0s3 ip saddr 192.168.0.101 ip daddr 172.16.0.0/24
````
still not working.

Comment: "iifname enp0s3 ip saddr 192.168.0.101 ip daddr 172.16.0.0/24 accept"

is working. I guess I had to add accept at the end.

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Indeed I forgot `accept` in my answer. Answer fixed.